# Am able to create project (software) with REST on JIRA server, how do make sure its a Scrum project?

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

Able to create project on Jira server
here is my endpoint
http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue

here is my body;

```
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "Test on Friday",
       "description": "... Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
       },       
        
        "reporter": {
            "name": "johndoe"
        },
        "priority": {
            "name": "Highest"
        }
   }
}
```

how can I create this as a scrum software  project?

Comment: Your question seems a bit jumbled. The title says "...how to make sure it's a Scrum project?"

Then you said you were using the endpoint 'http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue', but that's an endpoint for creating *Issues*, not Projects. Next, you've provided a Body example for the request, but it too contains parameters to define an *Issue*, not a Project.

Are you trying to create an Issue in a Project, or create a new Scrum Software Project?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the doc at https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/project-createProject
it looks like a projectType is needed.
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/JIRA-API-7-1-0-Create-Project/qaq-p/551444 may help
but I would use Chrome, Inspect, Network to find out the params that really get passed when creating a Scrum project